# Mean of one variable when another variable equals 1 in matlab

Tags: subset, mean

I would like to get the mean of my reaction time column when my stimnum column is equal to 1

I am not sure if i can do this with one simple line of code or if i need to do a for loop.

```
stimnum = randi([1 3], [1 100]);
y = 1 + 1.*randn(1, 100); 
rt = (y.^2) +.01;           
A = rand(1,100); 
correct = A>=0.2; 
Data= [stimnum; rt; correct ]';
Data = dataset({ Data, 'Stimnum', 'RT', 'Correct'});
rtmean = mean (Data.RT{Data.Stimnum == 1});
```

Comment: you should add the tag "matlab"

Comment: Just needed to change the bracket type around my call of the data
`rtmean1 = mean (Data.RT(Data.Stimnum == 1));`